# Django how to design the editting page of a plugin made by CMSPlugin and CMSPluginBase?

Tags: python, django, django-models, plugins, frontend

I am implementing a plugin to show the information of a publication, in the normal editting page, there's three button in the right down corner 'Cancel' 'Delete' 'Save', the plugin is created using CMSPlugin and CMSPluginBase, is it possible for me to add new buttons with them?

I tried adding a button, but I can only add attributes to the class defined in the cms_plugins.py. The button can only be added in the form, not on the window.

If it's impossible, please also let me know. Thanks so much!
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.